# Prove or Disprove : The set of discontinuous functions from [0,1] to R forms a ring with respect to pointwise addition and multiplication.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, continuity

Prove or Disprove : The set of discontinuous functions from [0,1] to **R** forms a ring with respect to pointwise addition and multiplication.
I know that the set of functions from **R** to **R** forms a ring under pointwise addition and multiplication.

Comment: The neutral function with resepect to the addition is the $0$-function, with respect to the multiplication, it is the $1$-function, Both functions are not discontinous, so the functions cannot form a ring.

Comment: **Stop asking or answering PSQs**.PSQ stands for Problem Solving Questions that specifically refer to that type of questions which ask you for an answer for a question without showing any efforts or working. This has been a matter of great discussion in Meta recently. We do not want to ruin our site into a homework solving place. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Neither the sum nor the product of two discontinuous functions need be discontinuous.

Consider $f+(-f)$ and $f\cdot \dfrac1f$.

Answer (score 1):

Pick any discontinuous function $f$ and $g=-f$, then $g+f$ is continuous and your operation is not closed under addition.